# Wordpress homepage redirects to anonymous page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hosting

hai guys i am face a serious problem with my wordpress hosted webpage on godaddy
it automatically redirects to some other page

url: http://hopeipswich.co.uk

and it takes to

http://sweeps1451.lifefree-or-diehard60.loan/?utm_medium=NQ3aDvyuBCtafRQJPeFC66tm%2bMNW8T%2baflxP0d0AJGo%3d&t=main5

i have checked the htaccess file and also updated permalinks of the site still it was not working, since the pages other than homepage working fine https://www.hopeipswich.co.uk/giving/

i didnt get any clue at all, any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, looks like you've been hacked. Take a deep breath and read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked